# Get content of the Google Docs editor

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I'm developing a Firefox extension that should work with Google Docs editor. Is there any way to retrieve the content of the opened document?

Comment: If there was an easy way for an extension to read my documents, I'd be a little worried...

Comment: Of course an extension can read the content of the document.  Extensions such as Firebug, HttpFox, etc. can intercept, read, process, and alter just about anything sent to the browser, loaded into it, or generated by it.  So OF COURSE, there's a way for an extension to grab the contents of an open document in Google Docs.  I think what the poster is looking for is an API method within Google Docs that would allow you to easily grab the HTML, and I'm sure there is somewhere, because the thing has to send the information back to the server to get saved.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the actual HTML of the Doc? If so you can use Firebug and highlight your document to get the HTML.

Firebug is open-source, so you should be able to find out how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's exactly where I started. Just somehow cannot figure out how to retrieve content from the new Google Docs editor. Tried different options in Firebug console. Had a hope that someone has already figured this out.